# How to create role assignments using Azure Active Directory Graph client in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I'm using this library : `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient`
class: `ActiveDirectoryClient`.

I'd like to give an Application (I have the appID) "Owner" access to some subscription. How would I go about doing that? Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Thanks for the edits Philippe. The following Powershell command does the job:

`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId.Guid`

However that is using the older style management calls. I can't come up with a mapping of the old-style calls to the new Resource Management calls

Answer (score 2):

The whole premise of this question is incorrect. The `GraphClient` is not the right client to manage such authorizations. The proper API library for that is `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Authorization`  and the class `AuthorizationManagementClient`.

I will post additional notes on the actual sequence of calls.

*** Update ***********

As promised here's the sample code:

```
    public static async Task<IServicePrincipal> GetServicePrincipalAsync(string accessToken, string tenantId, string clientId)
    {
        var graphClient = NewActiveDirectoryClient(accessToken, tenantId);
        var matches = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Where(sp => sp.AppId == clientId).ExecuteAsync();
        return matches.CurrentPage.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    private static ActiveDirectoryClient NewActiveDirectoryClient(string accessToken, string tenantId)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        tcs.SetResult(accessToken);
        return new ActiveDirectoryClient(
            new Uri($"{GraphApiBaseUrl}{tenantId}"),
            async () => { return await tcs.Task; });
    }
```

First you need to get the ObjectId of the principal you want to add. In the case of ServicePricipal I have a function that gets it from the directory like so:

Then using that and a scope ("/subscriptions/{my_subscription_id}", for the entire subscription) you can create a RoleAssignment:

```
    public static async Task AssignRoleToPrincipalAsync(
        string accessToken, 
        string subscriptionId, 
        string scope, 
        string roleName,
        string principalObjectId)
    {
        using (var client = NewAuthorizationManagementClient(accessToken, subscriptionId))
        {
            RoleDefinition roleDef = (await FindRoleDefinitionAsync(accessToken, subscriptionId, scope, roleName)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (roleDef == null)
                throw new Exception($"Role was not found: {roleName}");
            var props = new RoleAssignmentProperties()
            {
                PrincipalId = principalObjectId,
                RoleDefinitionId = roleDef.Id
            };
            await client.RoleAssignments.CreateAsync(scope, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), props);
        }
    }

    private static AuthorizationManagementClient NewAuthorizationManagementClient(string accessToken, string subscriptionId)
    {
        return new AuthorizationManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(accessToken)) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId};
    }
```

***** Update *****
To get the token using Azure.Identity you can use the following snippet

```cs
var accessToken = await new AzureCliCredential().GetTokenAsync(  
  new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }));

var client = new AuthorizationManagementClient(  
  new TokenCredentials(accessToken.Token))
  {
      SubscriptionId = subscription.Data.SubscriptionId
  };
```